# Definition of causality relation

Tags: special-relativity

It seems to me that special relativity has a weird definition of the causality relation. In that theory, the only thing that matters is the space-time distance between events. But I don't think this is the case. It seems to me that if I am pressing a few keys on my keyboard and then causing this question to appear on your screen, my action has a greater locus of influence than just me sleeping in bed. So, what exactly is the definition of the causality relation?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the definition of the causality relations are [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure).

But they do not do what you think it does: Events that causally precede another event are merely the events that *could have influenced* the event they precede (assuming that no causal influence is possible that is faster than light) - the causal relation does not make any statement about "how big" of an influence these events *actually have* on each other.

Forget relativity. A good analogy is to think of the surface of a lake: Assume the only physics there is are waves on the surface of the lake. The waves travel at a finite speed $v_s$ across the surface. Then, for an event on this surface fixed by $p := (t_0,x_0,y_0)$ (time and position on the surface), it's causal past is given by the cone $J^-(p) = \{(t,x,y) \vert t < t_0 \wedge \sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2} < v_s(t-t_0)\}$. The first condition ensures that the events in the cone really lie in the past of $p$, while the second ensures that the events are only so far away that a wave could have travelled far enough in the time $t - t_0$ between the past event and $p$ to actually reach $p$.

Waves that have been created outside this cone of events can never influence how tumultous the surface will be at $p$, since they could not have reached the position $(x,y)$ in the time they had available.

Now, if I understand your question correctly, you essentially ask why we treat all events in the causal past on equal footing. The answer is simple: *Because it is equally important if nothing happened at a point in the cause past as it is if something happened.* If we know that nothing happened at any of the events in the causal past, that the lake was perfectly still at any of these times,, then we know nothing will happen at $p$! The information "You typed on your keyboard at 3am." is not more or less valuable than the information "You did not type on your keyboard at 3am.". The causal relations are between *events*, fixed positions in space and time, *not* between physical objects.

Comment: But what does "could have" mean? That it happens in a possible world?

Comment: @user197952: *No*. That it is *not impossible* that what happens at the causally preceding event has an influence on what happens at the causally following event. See it that way: The set of initial values you need to plug into your equations to the determine the full future state at a single point is the set of states of a space-like (or, *achronal*) slice of the causal past of that point.

Comment: I guess this is a hard question to answer, because "potential" is hard to define.

Comment: These are deep questions that I suppose physics stack exchange is not the place to ask. Well, then what is a good place to discuss these things?

Comment: Have a bit of patience, I am currently expanding my answer to try to address you.

Comment: @user107952 In classical special relativity, event A "could have influenced" event B if the structure of spacetime would allow an information-carrying signal to propagate from A to B. In quantum field theory, it gets a little more complicated, but even in that case, a causal relationship between A and B amounts to the assertion that something that happened at A could influence something that happens at B. (There is a precise mathematical statement of this in terms of quantum fields.)

Comment: @user107952 Timelike separated events can have causal influence between them, but they don't have to. The concept of lightcones is not asking whether the past events actually took the opportunity to influence the future. It is only about what is possible with the speed of light. If there is no influence, OK. No problem. The possibility does not have to be exploited. Not even in some "other world". The causal influence doesn't have to be there. It is just a possible thing inside the past light cone.